# Tokenizing Named Entities in Spacy

Tags: nlp, tokenize, spacy, named-entity-recognition

can anyone assist please.

I'm attempting to tokenize a document using Spacy whereby named entities are tokenised. For example:

'New York is a city in the United States of America'

would be tokenized as:

['New York', 'is', 'a', 'city', 'in', 'the', 'United States of America']

Any tips on how to do this are very welcome. Have looked at using span.merge(), but with no success, but I am new to coding so am likely to have missed something.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What code do you have so far? Are you using the NER tagging feature of Spacy to identify the start and end of entity tokens?

Comment: I've made some progress, here is the code:

import spacy

from spacy.pipeline import merge_entities

print('setting up pipeline')
coref_nlp = spacy.load('en_coref_md')
spacy_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

spacy_nlp.add_pipe(merge_entities)
spacy_nlp.add_pipe(spacy_nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))

doc = 'New York is a city in the United States of America. It is an exciting place to visit'

print('applying pipelines')
new_doc = spacy_nlp(coref_nlp(doc)._.coref_resolved) # replace co-reference entities with root reference

Comment: And here is how its Tokenized:

doc_array = []
print('Tokenizing document')

for sentence in new_doc.sents:
    doc_array.append([(token.text).lower() for token in sentence if (not token.is_stop and token.pos_ != "PUNCT" and token.text != '\n')])

print(doc_array)

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how this could be improved? The main document I'm looking to analyse is George Bush's post-9/11 speech:

https://millercenter.org/the-presidency/presidential-speeches/september-22-2001-address-us-response-attacks-september-11

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you pasted in comments using the proper markdown to format it as code. Code pasted in comments is hard to review. If you format code properly and add to your question, the likelihood of getting good answers is higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`doc.retokenize`](https://spacy.io/api/doc#retokenize) context manager to merge entity spans into single tokens. Wrap this in a [custom pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes), and add the component to your language model.

```
import spacy

class EntityRetokenizeComponent:
  def __init__(self, nlp):
    pass
  def __call__(self, doc):
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for ent in doc.ents:
            retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end], attrs={"LEMMA": str(doc[ent.start:ent.end])})
    return doc

nlp = spacy.load('en')
retokenizer = EntityRetokenizeComponent(nlp) 
nlp.add_pipe(retokenizer, name='merge_phrases', last=True)

doc = nlp("German Chancellor Angela Merkel and US President Barack Obama "
          "converse in the Oval Office inside the White House in Washington, D.C.")

[tok for tok in doc]

#[German,
# Chancellor,
# Angela Merkel,
# and,
# US,
# President,
# Barack Obama,
# converse,
# in,
# the Oval Office,
# inside,
# the White House,
# in,
# Washington,
# ,,
# D.C.]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update: Spacy v3 has included the functions required.**

I also retract my expectation for 'president-elect' (as introduced in my original answer below) to remain a single entity (but this could depend on your use-case)

```
from pprint import pprint

import spacy
from spacy.language import Language


# Disabling components not needed (optional, but useful if run on a large dataset)
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["tok2vec", "parser", "senter", "lemmatizer", "tagger", "attribute_ruler"])
nlp.add_pipe("merge_noun_chunks")
nlp.add_pipe("merge_entities")
print('Pipeline components included: ', nlp.pipe_names)

example_text = "German Chancellor Angela Merkel and US President Barack Obama (Donald Trump as president-elect') converse in the Oval Office inside the White House in Washington, D.C."

print('Tokens: ')
pprint([
    token.text
    for token in nlp(example_text)
    # Including some of the conditions I find useful
    if not (
        token.is_punct
        or
        token.is_space
    )
])
```

Continue reading for original answer:

---

I think I have reinterpreted the accepted answer to work for spaCy v3. It appears to produce the same output at least.

On a side note, I noticed that it broke up a phrase such as "president-elect" into 3. I am ammending the original answer's example to include that in the hopes that someone will comment with an ammendment (or new answer)

---

```
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language


class EntityRetokenizeComponent:
    def __init__(self, nlp):
        pass

    def __call__(self, doc):
        with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
            for ent in doc.ents:
                retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end], attrs={"LEMMA": str(doc[ent.start:ent.end])})
        return doc

@Language.factory("entity_retokenizer_component")
def create_entity_retokenizer_component(nlp, name):
    return EntityRetokenizeComponent(nlp)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  # You might want to load something else here, see docs
nlp.add_pipe("entity_retokenizer_component", name='merge_phrases', last=True)

text = "German Chancellor Angela Merkel and US President Barack Obama (Donald Trump as president-elect') converse in the Oval Office inside the White House in Washington, D.C."
tokened_text = [token.text for token in nlp(text)]

print(tokened_text)

# ['German',
#  'Chancellor',
#  'Angela Merkel',
#  'and',
#  'US',
#  'President',
#  'Barack Obama',
#  '(',
#  'Donald Trump',
#  'as',
#  'president',
#  '-',
#  'elect',
#  ')',
#  'converse',
#  'in',
#  'the Oval Office',
#  'inside',
#  'the White House',
#  'in',
#  'Washington',
#  ',',
#  'D.C.']
```